# Can I use the central limit theorem for a sum of random variables, but one of them has a possibly different distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

I am trying to see if my solution is accurate. The question goes (I am aware that the question may have been asked before on this site, but nowhere have I seen a reason why the CLT can/cannot be used):

An engineer believes that $W$, the amount of weight (in units of $1000$ pounds) that a certain span of a bridge can withstand without structural damage, is normally distributed with mean $400$ and variance $40^2$. Suppose that the weight (again, in units of $1000$ pounds) of a car is a random variable with mean $3$ and standard deviation $0.3$. Approximately how many cars would have to be on the bridge span for the probability of structural damage to exceed $0.1$?

The reason I am asking if I can use the central limit theorum is because we do not know the distribution of the weight of each car. However, here is my work:

I started by defining $C_n$= total weight of $n$ cars. We need to find n such that:
$$P(C_n\geq W)>.1\to P(C_n-W\geq0)>.1$$
Can I use the central limit theorem and say:
$$P(C_n-W\geq0)>.1=P\left(\frac{(C_n-W)-E(C_n-W)}{\sqrt{Var(C_n-W)}}\geq\frac{0-E(C_n-W)}{\sqrt{Var(C_n-W)}}\right)>.1$$
$$\approx1-\phi\left(\frac{-E(C_n-W)}{\sqrt{Var(C_n-W)}}\right)>.1\to\phi\left(\frac{-E(C_n-W)}{\sqrt{Var(C_n-W)}}\right)\leq.9$$

I found:

$E(C_n-W)=E(C_n)-E(W)=nE(C_i)-400=3n-400$

Since all $C_i$ are independent, and $C_n$ and $W$ are independent: $Var(C_n-W)=Var(C_n)+Var(W)=nVar(C_i)+Var(W)=.3^2n+1600=.09n+1600$

After simplifying, I got $n>116.2$, therefore the $n$ at which the probability exceeds $.1$ is $117$.

Is this a valid proof, or did I assume too much by using the central limit theorum?

Comment: A linear combination of independent, random normal variables is again a normal random variable. Thus you can use the CLT to get $C_n$ is (approximately) normal, and then $C_n-W$ is also normal.

Comment: Thank you, so since $C_n$ and $W$ are normal, did I use the CLT correctly?

Comment: If you used the CLT to get $C_n$ is normal, then yes you used it correctly. Your work looks right to me.